# vue3 - can't render facebook comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, vue.js, plugins, vuejs3

I am trying to add a Facebook comments plugin ([check it here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)) to my vue app, the problem is that div is created in DOM but it sometimes shows, sometimes not(width: 0, height 0)

[image]

Note: I am calling XFBML.parse function, my host is added to fb app

This is my current code:

```
<template>
    <div
        ref="commentContainer"
        class="fb-comments"
        :data-href="onUrl()"
        :data-width="cwidth"
        :data-numposts="numposts"
    ></div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import router from "../../router";
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        cwidth: {
            type: String,
            default: "100%",
        },
        numposts: {
            type: String,
            default: "2",
        },
    },
    setup({ cwidth, numposts }) {
        const commentContainer = ref(null);
        const init = () => {
            if (
                window.FB &&
                !commentContainer.value.hasAttribute("fb-xfbml-state")
            ) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.FB.XFBML.parse(commentContainer.value.parentElement);
                }, 2000);
            }
        };
        onMounted(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                init();
            }, 1500);
        });
        const onUrl = () => {
            return document.location.origin + document.location.pathname;
        };

        watch(
            () => router.currentRoute.value,
            () => {
                init();
            }
        );

        return { cwidth, numposts, commentContainer, onUrl };
    },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `setTimeout` try using `nextTick` and not passing any params to the parse function.

E.g. in the mounted function

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
    window.FB.XFBML.parse()
  })
```

Are you waiting 1.5s before running `init()` for a reason?

The above works using Vue2, for Vue3 example see below:

```
import { createApp, nextTick } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const init = async () => {
      await nextTick()
      window.FB.XFBML.parse()
    }
  }
})
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#nexttick

Also, make sure you have added the SDK script and provided `fb-root` div to your index.html. It would not work on mine unless I added these just before the closing `</body>` tag.

I also had to add the the nextTick code to the route watcher to force the window to parse FB again when a new page is navigated to. I'm unsure of the Vue 3 version but I'm sure you can figure it out from this example:

```
watch: {
    $route (to, from) {
      if (to.fullPath !== from.fullPath) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          window.FB.XFBML.parse()
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you suggest any alternative of nextTick for vue3?

as I guess your code snippet is for vue2

Comment: Ah yes, correct. You will need to import nextTick from Vue as you do with onMounted and then you use it like so - await nextTick() - but make sure wherever you are calling this it is in an async block.

Further refs - https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#nexttick

I have updated my original answer with this.

Comment: @B.Ch. did this solve your issue or help in any way??

Comment: Yes, I solved. I don't know why but it was not working on localhost, but worked in production

Comment: @B.Ch. From my experience most if not all Facebook plugins such as comments don't work on a local environment because the Facebook app you create cannot link to localhost. It's possible it might work if you were to use something like ngrok as the URL in the Facebook app but I'm not sure. I have a staging environment so was able to test the comments plugin there before it went to production.